# Is it ok to post both on mathematica.stackexchange.com and Wolfram community?

Tags: discussion, support

Is it ok to post both on mathematica.stackexchange.com and Wolfram community?

There seems to be a difference in that community is supposed to be for "discussions" whereas this mathematica.se is strictly for questions.

Comment: IMO it's ok if you post a link in each question making a cross reference. It make people of both communities to know better each other.

Answer (score 8):

StackExchange has a policy against cross posting between several StackExchange sites.  There is no such policy against posting both on Mathematica.StackExchange and a non-StackExchange site though.

**If you post both on Wolfram Community and here, please do cross link the two posts!**  Each post should have a link to the other one.  This is to prevent duplication of effort.  Also, if you get a satisfactory answer on one site, do mention it on the other one, thus "closing" the thread.

I have cross posted on occasion, to reach a wider audience, especially when I had a question about a topic few people are experts in.